# How to generate loops and conditionals using the codemodel library

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I've been trying to learn how to use Suns **codemodel** library and I'm absolutely stumped with **generating** for loops and if-else blocks. I'm struggling with how to generate the conditions for the if-else blocks and the for loops, but also on how to generate the body of these as well.

For example:

```
if (condition) { //How is this condition generated?
     //How is this body filled?
} else {

}
```

For the loop:

```
for(condition) {  //How is this condition generated?
   //How is this body filled?
}
```

Comment: for is unrelated to if and else. It's unclear what you want to do here. If you want to continue to do something while a condition is true, then use while(condition). If you want to either do one thing or another thing depending on the truth of a condition, just use if and else. Bodies are just a series of statements, same as wherever you're putting your if/else.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in what I wrote. I can't figure out how to write the body of the if-else blocks as well as how to write the condition for the for loop and its body as well.

Comment: To anyone as confused by this question as I was, Sun Codemodel is apparently a Java library for generating Java code, so the question is not "How do I program?" but "How does this particular library work?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im going to assume you already have a class and method defined.

To write a condition if/else statement you need to use the `_if()` and `_else()` methods on the `JBody` class.  This adds the statement to the body of the method you have defined.  from these methods you can reference and add to their bodies by calling the `_then()` method on the `_if()` or `_else()` returns the `JBody` directly.  Here's an example:

```
JConditional condition = body._if(input.lt(JExpr.lit(42)));
condition._then().add(
    codeModel.ref(System.class).staticRef("out").invoke("println").arg(JExpr.lit("hello"))); 
condition._else().add(
    codeModel.ref(System.class).staticRef("out").invoke("println").arg(JExpr.lit("world")));
```

which outputs:

```
if (input< 42) {
    System.out.println("hello");
} else {
    System.out.println("world");
}
```

To write a for loop, there are a couple of options.  The traditional for loop is written using the `_for()` method on the JBlock, which allows you to chain the `init()`, `test()` and `update()` methods corresponding to the various parts of the for loop declaration:

```
JForLoop forLoop = body._for();
JVar ivar = forLoop.init(codeModel.INT, "i", JExpr.lit(0));
forLoop.test(ivar.lt(JExpr.lit(42)));
forLoop.update(ivar.assignPlus(JExpr.lit(1)));

forLoop.body().add(
    codeModel.ref(System.class).staticRef("out").invoke("println").arg(ivar));
```

which outputs:

```
for (int i = 0; (i< 42); i += 1) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

For kicks, here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/johncarl81/7647146

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: There is no JBody class on [CodeModel](https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/)? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it is returned when defining a block. For instance when calling] [method.body()](https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JMethod.html#body())